# Multiple farms in a sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, farm, multiple-farms

Can there be multiple farms in a SharePoint server. Currently i'm having one farm in SharePoint and wondering if it is possible to have one more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. one server can have only SharePoint farm. But you have to mutliple farm's database on single SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. The long answer is it might be useful if we understood what you are trying to do. Why would you want multiple farms on a single server? If you need multiple URLs you can create several web applications or use host named site collections. If it is a security concern then this again can be achieved with separate web applications and content databases.